# Do I need to include css and js files in the lightbox page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Do I need to load all the css and js files again in my lightbox html code?
The css seems to work fine. But the js functions do not work in the lightbox page. Those js files are included in the parent html page and triggered in the same file.

only the jquery code that I have written in the lightbox html code works in the lightbox page. The other js functions written in the included js files do not work.

Should I use any different methods to trigger the js functions which are included in the parent page in the lightbox page??

**Edit**

Lightbox html code:

```
<div id="lightbox-holder">
    <div class="result">
         <p>Total Amount</p>
         <h3>1000</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="equal-sign"> </div>

    <div class="left-stepper">  //Stepper input
      <label class="steper-label">Left stepper</label>
      <input type="text" id="spinner1" class="ui-stepper" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div class="plus-sign"> </div>

    <div class="right-stepper"> //Stepper input
        <label class="steper-label">Right Stepper</label>
        <input type="text" id="spinner2" class="ui-stepper" value="0" />
    </div>  
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function (){

        func.init();

        $('#cost_allocation').live('click', function() {   
            $(this).hide();
            $('#help_icon').hide();
            $('#breakdown').show();  

            $('#ok_button').hide();
            $('#save_button').show(); 
        });

        $('#save_button').live('click', function(){
            $("#jQLightboxContents").remove();
            $("#jQVeil").remove();

        });
});
</script>
```

This jQuery inside the lightbox page works. But the js functions triggered through func.init() do not work.

The func.init() is for triggering all the js files required for this code to work. For example, the stepper input unit(numeric stepper) code is written in a file named stepper.js  and it is triggered using the init function. This works well in the parent page, but is not displayed in the lightbox page. Should I invoke the init() function in a different way?

Comment: light box mean??? http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ ???

Comment: Give us some code! Or jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not. Since the lightbox us actually in the same page, there is no need to reinclude any files.

Comment: But I have to place a stepper in my lightbox. The stepper functionality is defined in a js file named stepper.js. It is included in the parent page and triggered through an init() function. But those steppers are not displayed in the lightbox. What could be the problem?

Comment: What the hell is a stepper? It sounds to me like there are events you might need to attach using live() or similar. I really think you need to jsFiddle this one and I'd be happy to try and help.

Comment: I have a lots of supporting js files in my local machine.. How do I load them in jsFiddle?

Comment: Drop them somewhere reachable and add them under the resources section

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet would help.

In any case, the lightbox code is a part of the body tag in your html and is not a standalone html. So **no**, you do not need to include your js again.